# Issues while upgrading from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.7 to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 4.2

Tags: containers, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I had this code previously working while using the `StorageClient.dll`:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(courseName.ToLower(), blobClient);
container.CreateIfNotExist();
```

When upgrading to the Storage.dll and using the Storage.Blob I am unable to call the CreateIfNotExists method with empty parameters. I have looked at the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.createifnotexists.aspx

There are now 2 constructors:

```
CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists (BlobContainerPublicAccessType, BlobRequestOptions, OperationContext)
CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists (BlobRequestOptions, OperationContext)
```

I have attempted to creat the `BlobRequestOptions` and `OperationContext` and pass them in as follows but without joy:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(courseName.ToLower());
var bro = new BlobRequestOptions();
var oc = new OperationContext();
container.CreateIfNotExist(bro,oc);
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can still call it as CreateIfNotExists(), since those arguments have default values. Also please note that GetContainerReference requires a name to be passed in, not a URL.